# Finding the surface area of a sphere within a cylinder and above the $xy$-plane using double integral

Tags: integration, geometry, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I'm trying to find the surface area of the part of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ that lies within the cylinder $x^2+y^2=ax$ and above the xy-plane.

I want to do this using $$A(S)=\iint_D \sqrt{[f_{x}(x,y)]^2+[f_{y}(x,y)]^2+1} \; dA.$$
My understanding is that $f=z=\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}$, $z_x=-x(a^2-x^2-y^2)^{-1/2}$,  $z_y=-y(a^2-x^2-y^2)^{-1/2}$.

What I don't understand is what the bounds for the integrals should be. I think it has to be done using polar coordinates, but I'm lost as to what the radius and angle bounds would be -- I'm not visualizing the cylinder and sphere very well.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is easier to evaluate using polar coordinates. Based on your working,

$\displaystyle \sqrt{1+z_x^2 + z_y^2} = \cfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}}$

$\displaystyle dS = \cfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}} \ dx \ dy$

So integral to find surface area of sphere inside the cylinder above xy-plane is,

$\displaystyle \int_{x^2+y^2 \leq ax} \cfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}} \ dx \ dy$

Converting to polar coordinates,

$x = r \cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta, x^2 + y^2 = r^2$

$x^2 + y^2 \leq ax \implies r \leq a \cos\theta, - \frac{\pi}{2} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

[please note the bounds of $\theta$. As we are using polar coordinates centered at the origin, the circle $r = a \cos\theta$ forms for $\theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2} \right) \ $]

So the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{a\cos\theta} \cfrac{a}{\sqrt{a^2-r^2}} \ r \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. To get the angle bounds, did you take the interval where cos is positive in order to avoid a negative radius?

Comment: This is circle $(x - a/2)^2 + y^2 = a^2/4$ with center at $(a/2, 0)$ and radius $a/2$. So yes it forms for $x \geq 0$. As we are measuring radius from the origin, it is given by $a \cos \theta$ and varies with $\theta$. Radial distance measured from origin is $0$ at $-\pi/2$ and max at $\theta = 0$ and again $0$ at $\pi/2$.

Comment: How did you get that equation for the circle?

Comment: The equation I wrote above in the comments? That is $x^2 - 2 \cdot \frac{a}{2} x + y^2 = 0 \implies (x - \frac{a}{2})^2 - \frac{a^2}{4} + y^2 = 0$